# Store facebook display picture of user into mysql table using the facebook registration plugin

Tags: mysql, facebook, plugins, registration

Can facebook registration plugin also store display picture of the user who is registering along with the other details into a mysql database?

If yes, does anyone knows how to ?

Answer (score 1):

- **Sweet and short**

All you *really* need is the users ID.  With that you can simply place an `<img>` tag with the `src` attribute pointing to -

```
`http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture`
```

The users public profile picture should be displayed.
Live demonstration -  [image] 
 
([check the source for proof!](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/posts/10389267/edit))

---

- **Longer and more robust**

You don't need to use that plugin in order to retrieve users profile pictures.

You can use any other means you feel comfortable with to obtain that data.  There are many options in many languages.  Any Language that can perform HTTP requests can achieve the same results.

For simplicity I will demonstrate with the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) - If you are following along, you should know that the SDK requires the existence of a `<div>` element with the id of `fb-root`

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

On to the JavaScript -

```
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

FB.api('/USER_ID/picture', function(response) {
  alert(response);
});
```

The browser should alert you with the URL to the users profile picture.